# Windows Subsystem Kali Linux 13: Permission denied

Tags: kali-linux, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have installed Kali linux version `Linux DESKTOP-0667P5P 4.4.0-18362-Microsoft #476-Microsoft Fri Nov 01 16:53:00 PST 2019 x86_64 GNU/Linux` as a subsystem on my machine that is running Windows 10, I't seems that I have installed the very basic version of Kali and I was trying to install the full version using this command `sudo apt-get install kali-Linux-full`, but I ran into the same error in this [post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/554979/sudo-apt-fix-broken-install-error).

I have tried the one and only answer posted there which is running the command

`sudo mv /var/cache/apt/archives/jsql-injection_0.81-0kali2_all.deb \
/var/cache/apt/archives/jsql-injection_0.81-0kali2_all.deb.old`

but it gives me the error of `Permission Denied`.

I've also tried running `sudo apt-get clean` but produces the error below:

`Problem unlinking the file jsql-injection_0.81-0kali2_all.deb - pkgAcquire::Clean (13: Permission denied)`

I am able to Log in to root using `sudo su` but it still gives me permission denied.

Comment: What exact command gives you that error? What version number of Windows and what version of Kali are you doing this with?

Comment: Thanks @Alex I have clarified my post a bit more I hope that helps.

Comment: I know this is late! but this may help other with the same problem! i've got this fixed: This link could help : https://askubuntu.com/questions/772846/apt-get-update-unlinking

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your windows virusscanner is blocking it? I know I tried to install metasploit on Kali in WSL and my virusscanner went batshit crazy of all the exploit data. Which makes sense but I hadn't thought about it beforehand.